# Filter collection without duplicates

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel collection like the below:

```
[
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Product 1",
      "awards":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Award 1",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":2,
               "award_id":1
            }
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Award 2",
            "description":"Quae sint vero id iste.",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":2,
               "award_id":2
            }
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"Award 3",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":2,
               "award_id":3
            }
         },
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Product 2",
      "awards":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Award 2",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":3,
               "award_id":12
            }
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"Award 3",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":3,
               "award_id":13
            }
         },
         {
            "id":14,
            "name":"Award 4",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":3,
               "award_id":14
            }
         },
      ]
   }
]
```

Is there a way I can get a collection like the following, all awards, no duplicates:

```
      "awards":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Award 1",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":2,
               "award_id":1
            }
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Award 2",
            "description":"Quae sint vero id iste.",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":2,
               "award_id":2
            }
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"Award 3",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":2,
               "award_id":3
            }
         },
         {
            "id":12,
            "name":"Award 2",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":3,
               "award_id":12
            }
         },
         {
            "id":14,
            "name":"Award 4",
            "pivot":{
               "product_id":3,
               "award_id":14
            }
         },
      ]
```

I'm aware that the Laravel collection class has a number of methods (like filter etc) but I'm struggling to get them to work 'across objects' – for example here I have two objects that I almost want to

```
combine('awards')->unique()
```

...Kind of thing.

#### Edit

I'm getting the initial array pretty simply, a box contains a number of products and the products have awards, so I'd like to say, collectively the box has x, y, z award. Anyway, here is the query (the above is the result of `return $box`):

```
$box = Box::with('products.awards')->find($id);
```

Comment: Instead of getting the awards by product you maybe should get the awards from the db right away? Can you show us the query that leads to this result?

Comment: Added to question. I already use the products elsewhere in the view so it didn't make too much sense to get them from the db independently, but I'm open to the option of that (quite new to Laravel so not 100% on best practises etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way I can think of:

```
$awards = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
foreach($products as $product){
    $awards = $awards->merge($product->awards);
}
```

The nice thing about `merge` and Eloquent collections in general is that they use the id as unique identifier so your duplicates will be eliminated automatically.

Answer (score 4):

There's real simple way to do it.

```
$awardsArray = $products->lists('awards');
$awardsDirty = new Collection($awardsArray);
$awards = $awardsDirty->unique();
```

Answer (score 2):

After version of Laravel **5.2**, the `collection->lists()` have been marked as a **deprecated** method. For the alternative solution will be:

```
$awards = collect($products)
        ->pluck("awards")
        ->flatten(1)
        ->unique("id");
```